# Why is TextMate treating two spaces as a single character?

Tags: editor, textmate

When I enter two spaces into TextMate 1.5.7, under certain circumstances it seems to treat the two spaces as a single character..

For example when typing `("[space][space]")`

```
("  |")
     \_ the cursor
```

If I then press backspace, both spaces get deleted, and if I press the left arrow it jumps both spaces (which is surprisingly annoying)

It's nothing to do with my soft-tabs setting (which is set to 4 space soft-tab).. Has anyone else noticed this?, or is it something strange with my configuration (unlikely as it happened with a clean install, on a new OS install)?

I've since updated to v1.5.8, and the issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

The double spacing is caused by soft tabs.  At the bottom of Textmate where the column indicator, line indicator, file type, and tab size indicators are, click on the soft tabs drop down and click soft tabs to turn it off.

Comment: Not really using TextMate much anymore, but should this be happening in the middle of lines? I'd expect backspace to "delete a soft tab" at the start of a line, but not elsewhere in the line

Answer (score 0):

Consider that textmate is an editor for programmers. in most programming languges the number of spaces doesn't matter, so it doesn't seem to me that strange.

Anyway, I use 1.5.8 and I don't have this problem. I also looked in the configuration window and I can't see anything about it.